# Transition animation within the same activity after button press

Tags: java, android-animation

I have an activity in which after I press a Button I change the visibility of Group A from visible to gone, and the visibility of Group B from gone to visible.

I would like to simulate the same default animation you get when you go from one activity to another after pressing my button (while I remain in the same activity).

I have been looking online, but I have only been able to find examples of overridePendingTransition, which doesn't apply to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.groupA);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slideup);
        Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slidedown);

        if(layout.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){

            layout.startAnimation(slideUp);
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

slideup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0"
android:fromYDelta="500"
android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

slidedown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="500"
android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```